# Why can't I add parameters to my Google Script - Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, query-string, url-parameters

I created a Google Spreadsheet and created a bound Google Script (Tools > Script Editor) and then published as a Web App.

The docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) say that I can add parameters to my script url however they don't work and just display a Google error page. The only parameter that works is **prefix**

Example of a parameter(error):
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxCTsVDtE89J4FzV_mx-svHkGtRof7L3qg9iKtQgpGgcn6cbbI/exec?pid=1

Example of using prefix(works):
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxCTsVDtE89J4FzV_mx-svHkGtRof7L3qg9iKtQgpGgcn6cbbI/exec?prefix=testFunction

Example of a parameter with and the prefix parameter(error):
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxCTsVDtE89J4FzV_mx-svHkGtRof7L3qg9iKtQgpGgcn6cbbI/exec?pid=1&prefix=testFunction

Comment: Parameters work just fine.. you just find one that can't be used: "pid". Try any other.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu ah wow! good pick up. This should be in the docs.

Comment: Yes, I agree. There's probably others in that "blacklist" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are reserved parameters and Google has stated they will not fix this. I can't find a list but I know these do not work:

- c
- sid
- pid